Some details about variational calculation on variational bi-complex
I am reading 1801.07064, where the covariant phase space formalism is elaborated.
From what I have learnt from classical mechanics, the variation of Lagrangian for field theory $L[\Phi,\partial\Phi]$ is
$$
\delta L= \frac{\delta L}{\delta \Phi^i}\delta\Phi^i+\partial_{\mu}\Theta^{\mu}
$$
where $$\Theta^{\mu}[\delta\Phi^i,\Phi]:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \partial_{\mu}\Phi^i}\delta\Phi^i$$
if we switch everything here to its Hodge dual, then we can write
$$\delta\mathrm{L}=\frac{\delta \mathrm{L}}{\delta \Phi^i}\delta\Phi^i+d\Theta[\delta\Phi^i,\Phi]$$
where we define $\mathrm{L}:=Ld^nx$ and $\Theta := \Theta^{\mu}(d^{n-1}x)_{\mu}$ which are all Hodge dual of $L$ and $\Theta$
If we now consider Grassmann odd vertical differential operator $\delta$ on jet bundle. In 1801.07064. It is said that because of grassmann odd property. The variation now becomes
$$\delta\mathrm{L}=\frac{\delta \mathrm{L}}{\delta \Phi^i}\delta\Phi^i-d\Theta[\delta\Phi^i,\Phi]$$
My Question is: I tried to figure out the details on this minus sign but failed. Here is my try:
$$
\delta \mathrm{L} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \Phi^{i}}\delta\Phi^{i}d^{n}x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \partial_{\mu}\Phi^{i}}\delta(\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{i})d^nx 
$$
I am really skeptical about the next steps here, how can we pull $\partial_{\mu}$ out of $\delta$ on jet bundle? Isnt it one of vertical (0,1)-form bases as an integral? Is that some thing like this?
$$
d(\delta \phi) = -\delta d\phi = -\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi dx^{\mu}) = -\delta(\partial_{\mu}\phi)\wedge dx^{\mu}
$$
But I still cant get the minus sign there.
